# 404 Error on WordPress Site index file for Chrome only

Tags: wordpress

A relative asked me to fix some things on their website and I noticed that there was an error on Chrome. The home page would return the following text:

> No Results Found

> The page you requested could not be found. Try refining your search, or use the navigation above to locate the post.

The rest of the website functions normally, it is only the home page that has this issue. The Developer tools on Chrome return this error:

```
(index):1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) contentscript.js:73 undefined (index):1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received. DSC_0943-1274378_74x74.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (index):12 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules
    at et_core_page_resource_fallback (http://website.com/:12:154)
    at HTMLLinkElement.onload (http://website.com/:54:325) et_core_page_resource_fallback @ (index):12 onload @ (index):54 (index):1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I have already saved permalinks and modified the *.htaccess* file and I am genuinely at a loss. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: disabled all installed extensions in Chrome

Comment: @KanonChowdhury, the problem is not with only my Chrome, but everyone's Chrome. One user left a comment on there stating that it wasn't working and it is only the home page, (index).